# Is Juma prayer valid if I pray outside of the mosque boundary?

Tags: salat, sunni

Our mosque is full and when we pray juma we pray it on the roads behind the imam while hearing what he recites. Is Juma prayer valid if prayed outside of the mosque's boundary like on the road or footpath behind the imam ?

Comment: Yes.  A mosque isnt a condition for the prayer to be valid.

Comment: @Kilise most madhabs consider the jami' mosque (not even any mosque) as a necessary condition beside the residency.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Could you elaborate?

Comment: The idea of friday prayer is to gatter all moslems of  city in one single place what i mentioned is what i read in an Nawawi's majmo' as the opinion of the shafi's and the majority of scholars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every part of the earth that is valid for performing prayer, is a mosque for the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) said: “The earth has been made for me (and for my followers) a place for praying and a thing to perform dry ablution” [recorded by Al-Bukhari].
Friday prayer consist of two parts, the Friday prayer Speech "khotbet aljuma" followed by shorter prayer.

If it is hard going to other mosque near you, It is fine to use a near space to this mosque as long as you can ensure the following:

- space outside the mosque must be clean ensuring no impurities that nullify the prayer.
- Can hear the speech clearly from its beginning with no difficulties.
- Not to be easily distracted from it by the surrounded environment like noises, cars, people walking outside the mosque, etc...
- your gathering outside the mosque doesn't imply harm to people using streets as blocking the traffic for other peoples and cars passing through.
- Everyone can do his pray comfortably in humbleness. as the space you pray in is not over crowded.

I would like adding that you are actually in the mosque premises, for example if your home is so close to the mosque where you can hear Imam very clearly and all your family members gathered with you in a clean area room dedicated for prayer. this will not be a Friday prayer at home.

as you should actually go to the mosque to meet other Muslim brothers.

God is most high and all knowledgeable.